# Poner el resultado en input text

Tags: php, zxing

Me interesa crear un lector de códigos de barras en PHP, y que se va a utilizar con Android.

He encontrado algo bueno, pero el resultado que pone después de escanear, me gustaría que sea en `input text` y la verdad que no lo consigo.

Me interesa en `input` para poder ser mandado después a una base de datos.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

</style>
<script>
function refreshPage(){
    window.location.reload();
} 
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //This entire block of script should be in a separate file, and included in each doc in which you want scanner capabilities
        function zxinglistener(e){
            localStorage["zxingbarcode"] = "";
            if(e.url.split("\#")[0] == window.location.href){
                window.focus();
                processBarcode(decodeURIComponent(e.newValue));
            }
            window.removeEventListener("storage", zxinglistener, false);
        }
        if(window.location.hash != ""){
            localStorage["zxingbarcode"] = window.location.hash.substr(1);
            self.close();
            window.location.href="about:blank";//In case self.close is disabled
        }else{
            window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e){
                window.removeEventListener("storage", zxinglistener, false);
                var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
                if (hash != "") {
                    window.location.hash = "";
            processBarcode(decodeURIComponent(hash));

                }
            }, false);
        }
        function getScan(){
            var href = window.location.href.split("\#")[0];
            window.addEventListener("storage", zxinglistener, false);
            zxingWindow = window.open("zxing://scan/?ret=" + encodeURIComponent(href + "#{CODE}"),'_self');
        }

    </script>

    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function processBarcode(b){
                    var d = document.createElement("div");
                    d.innerHTML = b;
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <button style="background-color:yellow;margin:auto;display:block" onclick="getScan()"><input type="image" src="http://www.whwplastics.com/QR/images/scan@2x.png" /></button>
</br>
  <button style="background-color:yellow;margin:auto;display:block" type="submit"  onClick="refreshPage()"><input style="width:50px;height:50px;" type="image" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/essentials-solid/100/Refresh-512.png" /></button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

El código funciona bien, solo que me gustaría que muestre los datos recibidos en `input text` para que yo pueda después mandar el formulario a MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un `input text` no tiene texto, sino tiene un value. Para poner datos tienes que ponerlos en un el value como así: `<input value="texto">`

Para javascript puedes utilizar `.value="texto"`. Así que en vez de utilizar un `.innerHTML` tienes que utilizar un `.value`